# Error creating a vector from a self-made function

Tags: r, function, if-statement

Trying to make my problem reproducible, I have the following vector:

```
trialvector <- as.vector(c("K", "K", "m", "m", "K"))
```

And this function to try to convert this vector into one which transforms "K" into a numeric 3 and "m" into a numeric 6, I want to assign this vector to a variable called `multiplier`:

```
 Expcalc <- function(vector)  {
 multiplier <<- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(vector))
 for (i in seq_along(vector)) {
   if (vector[i] == "K") {
     multiplier[i] <- 3
   } else if (vector[i] == "M" | i == "m") {
     multiplier[i] <- 6
   } else {
     multiplier[i] <- 0
   }
 }
}
```

Instead of getting the output I want (a Vector of 6 and/or 3 depending on which character was in `trialvector`, I get a vector full of zeros. and this error:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In Expcalc(trialvector) : NAs introduced by coercion
>   2: In Expcalc(trialvector) : NAs introduced by coercion

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `ifelse` which is vectorized and there is no need for a loop. Something like `ifelse(trialvector == 'k', 3, ifelse(trialvector == 'm', 6, NA))` or use `factor`, i.e. `factor(trialvector, levels = c('K', 'm'), labels = c(3, 6))` or the fancy `chartr`, i.e. `chartr('Km', '36', trialvector)`

Comment: The problem is that in my original vector I have around 70 levels, and It is not viable establish 70 labels within `factor()` function. I would need also something similar to  `else`, to gather all the cases in which I want zeros.

Comment: I gave you 3 options. Pick your favourite :)

Answer (score 0):

```
trialvector <- as.vector(c("K", "K", "m", "m", "K"))
```

```
trailvector
[1] "K" "K" "m" "m" "K"
```

```
Expcalc <- function(vector)  {
  multiplier <- as.vector(x = c(), mode = "numeric")
  for (i in vector) {
    if (i == "K") {
      multiplier <- append(multiplier, 3)
    } else if (i == "M" | i == "m") {

      multiplier <- append(multiplier, 6)
    } else {

      multiplier <- append(multiplier, 0)
    }
  }
  return(multiplier)
}

trailvector <- Expcalc(trialvector)
```

```
trailvector
[1] 3 3 6 6 3
```

I switched the for loop and then just appended the new values into the new vector. Output matches what you are looking for.